# How to Drop Table [LINKED_SERVER_POSTGRESQL].[DATABASE_NAME].[PUBLIC].[TABLE_NAME]?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, stored-procedures, linked-server

I made a linked PostgreSQL server on SQL Server, then I want to delete the existing table on the PostgreSQL through the stored procedure that I created on SQL Server.

When I execute the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY (LinkedSrvrName, ' DROP TABLE Database. MyTab SELECT NULL ')
```

An error appears like this OLE DB provider

> "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRE_2_14" returned message "ERROR: syntax error at or near" SELECT "; No query has been executed with that handle ".MSG 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRE_2_14"

Can anyone can help?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @DaleK I tried searching on the net and the answer I always get only this SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (LinkedSrvrName, ' DROP TABLE Database. MyTab SELECT NULL ') but after I run on SQL Server, an error appears like this **OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRE_2_14" returned message "ERROR: syntax error at or near" SELECT "; No query has been executed with that handle ".MSG 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRE_2_14"**

Comment: Please check the edits I have made to your question and ensure they are accurate.

Answer (score 0):

To run arbitrary commands at a linked server, enable RPC OUT for the linked server like this

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedSrvrName', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
```

and run

```
exec ('drop table whatever') at LinkedSrvrName
```